# upgrade from 0.12 to 0.13: Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/-/aws" to obtain

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to upgrade from terraform 0.12 to 0.13.

it seems to have no specific problem of syntax when I run `terraform 0.13upgrade` nothing is changed.

only a file `version.tf` is added

```
+terraform {
+  required_providers {
+    aws = {
+      source = "hashicorp/aws"
+    }
+  }
+  required_version = ">= 0.13"
+}
```

and when I run `terraform plan` I got

```
Error: Could not load plugin


Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

2 problems:

- Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/-/aws" to obtain
schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/-/aws"
- Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/-/template" to obtain
schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/-/template"
```

running `terraform providers` shows

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.bastion
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template]
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
└── module.vpc
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] >= 2.68.*

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/-/aws]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/-/template]
```

So my guess is form some reason I have `-/aws` instead of `hashicorp/aws` in my tfstate, however I can't find this specific string at all in the tfstate.

I tried:

- running `terraform init`
- `terraform init -reconfigure`
- deleting the `.terraform` folder
- deleting the `~/.terraform.d` folder

So I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this problem

Comment: Did you try a `terraform init -reconfigure`? What was the output?

Comment: According to the upgrade guide documentation explaining the `-` namespace for legacy providers (https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#why-do-i-see-provider-during-init-), it is not a root cause for your problem.

Comment: @MattSchuchard actually the replace provider command solved my problem, thanks :)

Comment: @allan.simon You should strongly consider filing a bug report on the issue tracker regarding this, since the documentation erroneously claims that command will only rectify a cosmetic issue, and not a functional issue. Either way, glad my doc link solved your issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I followed the steps [here](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#why-do-i-see-provider-during-init-)

```sh
terraform state replace-provider   registry.terraform.io/-/template  registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template
terraform state replace-provider   registry.terraform.io/-/aws  registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws
```

and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was bugging me.

Comment: But according to the doc you shouldn't need to!